# Why won't my title screen play button launch my game?

Tags: python, button, pygame, blit

I am trying to put a play button in my game. and when I launch the game I click the play button and it gives me an error

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Users\Zee_S\OneDrive\Desktop\python projects\lil Shooter\Player\Lil Shooter.py", line 370, in <module>
>    game_intro()
>    File "C:\Users\Zee_S\OneDrive\Desktop\python projects\lil Shooter\Player\Lil Shooter.py", line 336, in game_intro
>    button("LETS PLAY!", 20, 450, 115, 50, green, bright_green, run)
>    File "C:\Users\Zee_S\OneDrive\Desktop\python projects\lil Shooter\Player\Lil Shooter.py", line 308, in button
>    action()
> TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
> [Finished in 8.3s]
> ```

and I've looked at the code for this 'bool' thing but I cant find anything. here is the code for the buttons and title screen

```
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic, (x, y, w, h))
    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ((x + (w / 2)), (y + (h / 2)))
    screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def game_intro():
    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        screen.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Lilshooter", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
        screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("LETS PLAY!", 20, 450, 115, 50, green, bright_green, run)
        button("Quit", 480, 450, 100, 50, red, bright_red, quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
```

and this is where I called it in the game loop

```
run = True
game_intro()
while run:
    [...]
```

can I get help whit this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument to the function `button` needs to be a function. Therefore it cannot be `run` because `run` is a Boolean value.

If you want to change the status of the `intro` variable when the button is pressed, write a `startGame` function:

```py
def startGame():
    global intro
    intro = False
```

Pass `startGame` to `button`, instead of `run`:

```py
button("LETS PLAY!", 20, 450, 115, 50, green, bright_green, startGame)
```

Note the variable `intro` needs to be a variable in global namespace:
(see [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt))

```py
intro = True
def game_intro():
    global intro

    while intro:   
        # [...]
```

Comment: The thing is I only have run as a variable not a function

Comment: @Zina I've changed the answer. (I'm sad, it was a bautiful answer)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you so much you helped with a problem that I have been trying to solve for hours

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the name `action`. Your error is

> in button
> action()
> TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

It means that somewhere in the code you use`action` as function but it's a `bool`.
First, let's look at `action` in the `button()` function. We see that it is an input argument and that after an `if` check there is a possibility that `action` will be called as a function: the problem arises because the only check you make on `action` is that it is not None, so if it is not None but neither a function it will raise an error.
Somewhere in the code you invoke `button()` and pass it a `True` (or equivalent variable) as `action` argument.

In particular, button is invoked by `game_intro()` twice:

```
button("LETS PLAY!", 20, 450, 115, 50, green, bright_green, run)
button("Quit", 480, 450, 100, 50, red, bright_red, quitgame)
```

Since there is no initialisation of run inside `game_intro()`, I assume that the variable `run` is the same initialised outside the while loop (`run = True`).